# Pygame, cant get my surface to show on the display

Tags: pygame, pygame-surface

```python
import pygame
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((576,1024))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bg_surface = pygame.image.load('background-day.png')

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

screen.blit(bg_surface (0,0))


pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(120)
```

When running the code only a black screen shows and I cannot see my surface.

It shows that the problem is that "This code is unreachable" under the `screen.blit` line

If anyone knows how to fix this it would really help, Thank you

Comment: Also need a comma in there.  `screen.blit( bg_surface` **,** `(0,0) )`

Answer (score 1):

The `screen.blit` line, and the lines below it, are currently not contained in the `while True:`. You need to indent those lines once to place them inside the loop body.

That code is "unreachable" while outside of the loop because your code is looping infinitely (`while True`) and exiting when the `pygame.QUIT` event is found, thus the code beyond the loop body will never be executed.