# Why is the map not shown on pygame display?

Tags: python, pygame

Why doesn't my map appear on my pygame display?
I have used the number system for a map but still no result.

#### Code

Don't need to read the notes, they are for myself:

```py
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

clock = pygame.time.Clock()  

pygame.init() 
pygame.display.set_caption("Kemal AKsay") 

WINDOW_SIZE = (600, 400)  

ekran = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE, 0, 32)
display = pygame.Surface((300, 200))
oyuncu_görüntüsü = pygame.image.load("tt.png")
çimen_görüntüsü = pygame.image.load('çimen.png')
toprak_görüntüsü = pygame.image.load("toprak.png")

TILE_SIZE = çimen_görüntüsü.get_width()

game_map = [['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
            ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
            ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
            ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
            ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
            ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
            ['2', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '2'],
            ['1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1', '1'],
            ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
            ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
            ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
            ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
            ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']]

sağa_ileri = False
sola_ileri = False

oyuncu_konumu = [50, 50]  
oyuncu_y_hızı = 0

player_rect = pygame.Rect(oyuncu_konumu[0], oyuncu_konumu[1], oyuncu_görüntüsü.get_width(), oyuncu_görüntüsü.get_height())  

while True:  
    ekran.fill((146, 244, 255))  # bu arkaplan o 3 sayı rgb

    tile_rects = []
    y = 0
    for row in game_map:
        x = 0
        for tile in row:
            if tile == '1':
                display.blit(toprak_görüntüsü, (x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE))
            if tile == "2":
                display.blit(çimen_görüntüsü, (x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE))
            if tile != "0":
                tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE , TILE_SIZE))
            x += 1
        y += 1

    ekran.blit(oyuncu_görüntüsü, oyuncu_konumu,)  

    oyuncu_y_hızı += 0.2
    oyuncu_konumu[1] += oyuncu_y_hızı

    if sağa_ileri:
        oyuncu_konumu[0] += 1
    if sola_ileri:
        oyuncu_konumu[0] -= 1

    oyuncu_karesi = pygame.Rect(oyuncu_konumu[0], oyuncu_konumu[1], oyuncu_görüntüsü.get_width(), oyuncu_görüntüsü.get_height())

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                sağa_ileri = True
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                sola_ileri = True

        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                sağa_ileri = False
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                sola_ileri = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                alta_ileri = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                üste_ileri = False

    pygame.display.update()  
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: It's hard to read your code because it is not English. I suppose it's Turkish?! __Please explain__ and [edit] your question. You should clarify: (a) What does the given code? (b) What do you expect to be shown?

Comment: As an _Image is worth a thousand words_ (Bir Resim, Bin Kelimeye Bedeldir) it would help if you could upload and __paste your tiles__ (e.g. see [Formatting: Images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) using Imgur).

Comment: Still there are other issues making the question not ready to answer: (a) not reproducible without tiles, (b) game-objects (player and background tiles) moving out of the Surface, (c) background Surface `display` is black when blended. I want to point out issues that would help others, trying understand this specific Q&A journey.

Answer (score 1):

The *Surface* wich is associated to the screen is `ekran` instead of `display`. Since you draw the tiles on `display`, the are not visible on the screen.

Create the `display` *Surface* before the application loop and `blit` it on the `ekran` *Surface* in the application loop:

```py
# [...]

tile_rects = []
for y, row in enumerate(game_map):
    for x, tile in enumerate(row):
        if tile == '1':
            display.blit(toprak_görüntüsü, (x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE))
        if tile == "2":
            display.blit(çimen_görüntüsü, (x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE))
        if tile != "0":
            tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE , TILE_SIZE))

while True:  
    ekran.fill((146, 244, 255))  # bu arkaplan o 3 sayı rgb
    ekran.blit(display, (0, 0))
    ekran.blit(oyuncu_görüntüsü, oyuncu_konumu)

    # [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

### It shows a tile moving down

When I reproduced with following images:

1. blue as placeholder for "tt.png",
2. red as placeholder for 'çimen.png'
3. green as placeholder for "toprak.png"

I saw the **blue tile `tt.png`** entering on top, moving vertically down, and falling down at the end of the screen. With the right & left arrow-keys I could move it a bit to the right or left.

[image: pygame showing a tile falling down at the end of the screen]

After the blue tile disappeared as fallen through the window,
the game-loop continued adding tiles (even different ones) with `blit` to the Surface `display`.

### Issue: 2 Surfaces, one shown, the other with tiles

There are two *screens* (Turkish "ekran"), in PyGame we call it `Surface`, you are using:

- `ekran` as shown `Surface`
- `display` as hidden `Surface`

See your code given:

```py
// initially
ekran = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE, 0, 32)
display = pygame.Surface((300, 200))

// in the game-loop
while True:
    ekran.fill((146, 244, 255))  # bu arkaplan o 3 sayı rgb
    // here according to map the tiles are added to display 
    ekran.blit(oyuncu_görüntüsü, oyuncu_konumu, )
```

#### Different usages

This `ekran` as active Surface is shown in the open window.
On the otherhand `display` is currently an inactive Surface. But there all tiles are moved from the map. It is never shown.

### Read the docs for showing Surfaces

In the official PyGame docs there is an [example for opening a window on the screen](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode):

```
# Open a window on the screen
screen_width=700
screen_height=400
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])
```

Might be a bit confusing:

- the return value of `set_mode` is of type `Surface`.
- the return value of `set_mode` is shown in the open window.

### See also

- [Pygame, cant get my surface to show on the display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68147530/pygame-cant-get-my-surface-to-show-on-the-display)
- [What is the surface.blit() function in pygame? What does it do? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800894/what-is-the-surface-blit-function-in-pygame-what-does-it-do-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `display` does not reference the display, but references a surface in memory. This surface is never drawn to the actual display. If you replace `display.blit` by `ekran.blit` the output should appear on screen.